# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'srcObject')

Tags: reactjs

Hi i was trying to access the user camera and audio but i got the error "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'srcObject')", i didn't find a solution for the problem as i used refs but the problem persists.

```
/* all my refs */
const myVideo = useRef();
const userVideo = useRef();
const connectionRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);
        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You never define a `myVideo` variable

Comment: did you mean `userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typographical error, now I've modified the question

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever set an initial value for the `myVideo` reference so the `current` property is null (thus your error).

Comment: So what value should I have to initialize the ref with?

Comment: I gave it a value of "{}" and it works, but it doesn't show me the video (reference and autoplay are in the video)